# Debugging JNI HotSpot crashes

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jvm-hotspot

I am testing some custom JNI code on a remote Linux based system. I don't want to have to install DBX and JDB isn't being entirely helpful and diagnosing the issue. Is there any other light weight java JNI debugger that will actually show me where within the JNI code Im going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: If you're going to write native code, you need to use a native debugger. Period. And if you're doing anything non-trivial, you should use `valgrind` to make sure your native code isn't damaging anything else. Which, based on your posting, seems to be what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

In case of native code, you have to use gdb or anything else that is available. After all, once in JNI, you are debugging native code. It's no longer Java.